# MySQL calculate correspoding percentage to new column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

MySQL version 8.0

Hi say I have a table that looks like this:
Which I got after groupby count operation:

```
select number
     , count(number) as `count`
FROM (select *
           , CASE 
               WHEN column = 0 Then 0 Else 1 
             END AS number
      FROM table) t1;
```

result in:

```
number     count
  0         100
  1         900
```

Now for each number I want to add a column that gives corresponding percentage.

Desired:

```
number     count   percentage
  0         100        10
  1         900        90
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should show the original query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select
    t.*,
    count / sum(count) over() ratio
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, an option uses a subquery:

```
select
    t.*,
    count / (select sum(count) from mytable) ratio
from mytable t
```

This gives you a ratio between `0` and `1`; you can multiply it by `100` if you want a percentage.

Note that, if you are getting your original resultset from a query, it is very likely that this can be furthermore optimized. You might want to ask a new question, disclosing your original table(s) and query.

Comment: when using windowing function it takes care of conditional?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of your original query, it would be something like:

```
select number, count(*), count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from t
group by number;
```

If you want the percentage rather than ratio than multiply by 100.